# QGIS Field Calculator Help Results Always NULL

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a shapefile which is points and I created the table to include the x and y coordinates, now I also need to have the coordinates in DMS and DDS so I have gone to the field calculator and use the function to_dms but the resultant column is always a NULL even in other functions and other shape files...I must be missing something....also see the result image the column was created but only with NULL results.....I really hope its a quick fix that i am missing something as I have been trying to resolve this for the last two days.  [image: Results] [image: code used for filed calculator]

Comment: I suggest you make your output field type `text` instead of decimal.

Comment: Thank you....I cannot believe I was completely over thinking the issue...much appreciated....just one more the result with suffix to include the N or S doesn't always add it...is that a quick fix as well?  OOOps my fault again my string was too short all solved thanks again

Comment: Increase the field length would be my first try.

Comment: Thanks Erik.....again completely overthinking all working now.

Answer (score 2):

It was the input type it had to be a string and the length correct.